# Is G4jsf still being developed/supported?

Tags: jsf, gwt, richfaces

I've been evaluating different Java Web Application UI Frameworks. I have about 8 months of intensive [JSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) experience that I'd like to continue using. JSF also provides me the spider-readable markup as well as the ability to create very simple forms without touching much Java code.

I also will have need for thick-client side interfaces that will perform well with few server round trips. [GWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit) seemed like an ideal choice for this.

So, when I found [G4jsf](https://ajax4jsf.dev.java.net/nonav/ajax/gwt/gwt-cdk.html), I thought I had found the best of both worlds. However, I can't seem to find any active development on it. I hope it hasn't died, but it seems like that is the case.

Is there active development on this? Or am I two years too late?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on the conversation in the reference below, it seems that G4jsf is no longer being supported. If the poster is in fact Sergey Smirnov, I would imagine he'd be a pretty reliable source on the matter. :)

http://www.jboss.org/index.html?module=bb&op=viewtopic&t=150674